# What globally installed Python Packages should I uninstall?

Tags: python, pip, package

I have in the past installed Python packages through pip before entering the virtual environment (.venv) by accident, therefore installing them globally. Recently, I believe I've been having conflicts with said globally installed packages and wish to uninstall all the unnecessary ones, as i believe all my projects should install packages in their own virtual environments.

I'm not 100% sure, but believe some packages come with the initial Python installation. My question is, should i uninstall all of them or which ones should I keep, as they are standard to have globally? My current Python version is 3.8.1 and my currently installed global packages are listed below:

- certifi            2022.5.18.1
- charset-normalizer 2.0.12
- click              8.1.3
- colorama           0.4.6
- connectorx         0.3.1
- greenlet           1.1.2
- idna               3.3
- importlib-metadata 5.1.0
- itsdangerous       2.1.2
- Jinja2             3.1.2
- MarkupSafe         2.1.1
- pip                23.0.1
- pyparsing          3.0.9
- python-dateutil    2.8.2
- pytz               2022.7
- setuptools         41.2.0
- six                1.16.0
- SQLAlchemy         1.4.44
- threadpoolctl      3.1.0
- urllib3            1.26.14
- Werkzeug           2.2.2
- zipp               3.11.0

I have tried searching online, but could not seem to find any information regarding this. In particular, recently, I had a conflict downloading the library cryptography==38.0.3, that got solved by uninstalling a globally cached cffi package.

Comment: "I have in the past installed Python packages through pip before entering the virtual environment (.venv) by accident, therefore installing them globally"—this shouldn't happen unless you run `pip` with elevated privileges. _Never_ use `sudo` (or run things as Administrator on Windows) unnecessarily.

Comment: @Chris it can also happen on Windows with `%APPDATA%` installations or anything other than the default global `%PROGRAMFILES%` installation(if the user has write permissions to it).

Comment: In that case, the solution should be fairly easy. Since Windows doesn't ship with Python, it should be trivial to remove it and do a clean reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely remove all packages installed by pip, both system-wide and user-wide. Python does not come with Windows by default, so none of it is essential to the system itself

You can then simply reinstall Python afterwards to make sure everything is back to normal.

Unfortunately, pip still doesn't have a convenient to reliably remove all unused dependencies together with a package, which would make such situations much easier to recover from.

Comment: Because of it being a common source of breakage - many Linux distributions will soon start preventing users from being able to run pip as well as pip --user outside of virtual environments. Pip is already not installed by default on most of them as it is.